Swept out volume of solid half that of enclosing cylinder

Find a curve/ curves when rotated around x-axis contain half the enclosing cylinder volume.
$$ \dfrac{\pi\int_0^a y^2 dx}{\pi  b^2 a }=\dfrac12 $$
with initial conditions $ x=0,y=b, \frac{dy}{dx}=-\infty \text{ and } x=a,y=0 $
My thoughts were along calculus of variations lines with given arc length or given enclosed area before rotation around x-axis, but am curious where it would go if not constrained that way.
Thanks in advance.

This works:
$$
y = b \sqrt{\frac12 + \frac1\pi \sin^{-1}\left(1-\frac{2x}{a}\right)}
$$
All we need is that $y^2$ has area $ab^2/2$ under its graph. The above function is chosen such that $y^2$ is odd-symmetric about $(x,y)=(a/2,b^2/2)$, so it is guaranteed to have area $ab^2/2$. It is easy to check that it satisfies the other requirements too.
For $a=b=1$, here’s a plot of $y$:

and a plot of $y^2$:


More generally, given a strictly increasing continuous bijective odd function $f:[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ such that $f’(-1)=-\infty$, we can always take $y=b\sqrt{\frac12(1+f(1-\tfrac{2x}{a}))}$ to satisfy the given requirements. In the above example, I took $f(x) = \frac2\pi \sin^{-1}x$.
